# GridView e.RowIndex Assembly missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to create a GridView with Rows that are deleteable, hence passing rowKeys from client side to Server side:-

```
     <p>
        <strong>Existing Enrollments:-</strong></p>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvwenrollments" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames ="EnrollKey" EmptyDataText="No Data Found"
        SkinID="gridviewSkin2" OnRowDeleting="terminateForm">

        <Columns>......
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                <ItemTemplate><asp:Button ID="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" Width="45px"
                        ToolTip="Terminates an existing application."  OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');">
                    </asp:Button>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>   
        </Columns></asp:GridView>
```

On the server Side I have:-

```
protected void terminateForm(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        int newEnrollKey = int.Parse(gvwenrollments.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
..a bunch of code....}
```

I am getting an error that Error    3   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdatedEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'RowIndex'.

I have added System.Windows.Forms and System.Web.UI.WebControls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument type is incorrect. You need to use `GridViewDeleteEventArgs` instead of `GridViewUpdatedEventArgs`

So use

```
protected void terminateForm(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
```

Refer Official [**MSDN Docs**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: jeeezz... I was also developing an update functionality. Now I feel stupid. However my code works now, but the function never gets to run....

Comment: haha i still have a problem tho.. i cant' seem to get that function to run.... is there a way I can say onClientclick of the delete button:-<a href='default.aspx?enrollkey=" + EnrollKeyof that particularRow + "' onclick='return makesure()'>Delete</a>

Comment: @Philo `OnClientClick` should work, not sure but try with `CausesValidation="False"`

Comment: no go .. .the function never gets called. previously I had created a table format (before the Gridview) and I was passing the the EnrollKey with a page parameter and then on page load extracting the enrollKey and calling the terminate function with a single parameter enrollKey and that worked... can we replicate that process with the GridView?

Comment: @Philo, Just debug. Is function is getting called? And You can use `CommandArgument` property

Comment: when I click the delete button now, the page refreshes, goes to the Page_load function and then never goes into the terminate function...

Comment: Yes I have been debugging the function never gets called.